# imap_search SINCE criterion never returns results

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I am trying to access Gmail accounts to import Sent and Received Mails in a PHP application.
After each import, I store the current date in order to not import all mail each time.

```
// $this->dateLastSynchro is a DateTime object
$searchCriteria = 'NEW UNDELETED SINCE "' . $this->dateLastSynchro->format('r') . '" ';
$return = imap_search($this->mailBoxHandle, $searchCriteria);
```

The first import works fine (when I use `"ALL UNDELETED"`), but when I use SINCE, I never have results (even if I have sent or received new mails).

I have tried to use the format `Y-m-d` for date, but I have a PHP Notice when I do this (it says something like Unrecognized criterion).

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**

Solution suggested by Max works fine but I can't accept answer because it's a comment.

Comment: Perhaps you should store the last UID you got.  UIDs are guaranteed to increase as messages are added to the mailbox.

Comment: @Max : I can't find a search criterion on UIDs. Do I must retrieve all mails, loop through them and start importing when `UIDs > ref UID` ?

Comment: Changed to answer.  I'm not sure about your library, but the protocol allows UID SEARCH UID [uid]:* to search for messages from UID to end of mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should store the last UID you got. UIDs are guaranteed to increase as messages are added to the mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

The below works fine for me:

```
$imap    = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', "me@gmail.com", "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq");
$search  = imap_search($conn, 'ALL UNDELETED SINCE "28-OCT-12"', SE_UID);
```

(Note that PHP's imap API only uses the mail_criteria() function in the c-client library, and thus is using the IMAP2-style "SEARCH" command rather than IMAP4, due to resistance from the c-client maintainer(s) to provide a generic API for parsing SEARCH Commands into a SEARCHPGM.)

Comment: Yes, this works for me too, but when I'm done this, I have all undeleted mails and not only the new mails since the date.